# SQL - CASE WHEN troubles

Tags: sql, case-when

Running into an issue with a CASE WHEN statement. Sample script below:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Column1 = "Example 1" THEN "Name 1"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 2" THEN "Name 2"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" THEN "Name 3"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample1", "Sample2") THEN "Name4"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample3", "Sample4") THEN "Name5"
         ELSE "-" END AS Name,

    [aggregation language that doesn't affect the script]

FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Name IN ("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

The issue I'm having is that when executing the script "Name1", "Name2", and "Name3" all pull (and pull accurately), but "Name4" and "Name5" won't pull at all, presumably because they share a condition with "Name3" (Column1 = "Example3").

Essentially, I'm trying to pull both the aggregate that is "Name3" and it's components that are "Name4" and "Name5".

One way to think about it is that "Name3" is the NFL and "Name4" and "Name5" are the AFC and NFC, respectively.  Because I'm pulling in the NFL with the condition {Column1 = "Example3"}, it won't pull in the AFC and NFC, despite having a second required "AND" condition.

Would LOVE if someone could help here.  I've tried using parentheses, changing the order of the WHENs...no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the desired result set would look like?

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be to change the ordering of your cases:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Column1 = "Example 1" THEN "Name 1"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 2" THEN "Name 2"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample1", "Sample2") THEN "Name4"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample3", "Sample4") THEN "Name5"
         WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" THEN "Name 3" 
         ELSE "-" END AS Name,

    [aggregation language that doesn't affect the script]

FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Name IN ("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

With your current ordering, If "Name4" or "Name5" is true, "Name 3" will always be true, so it will get executed first.  With the modified ordering, "Name 3" will be true only if "Name4" and "Name5" come out to be false.  Make sense?

Comment: @Cooper, I would love to know if you were able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Would LOVE if someone could help here. I've tried using parentheses, changing the order of the WHENs...no luck.

You're not being entirely honest, are you?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11381/3/0 -- a simple switch of the `WHEN` conditions fixes your little problem. The lesson here is that testing stops at the *first* condition that's true.

Answer (score 0):

For "Name 3", you need to exclude the conditions of "Name 4" and "Name 5":

```
CASE WHEN Column1 = "Example 1" THEN "Name 1"
     WHEN Column1 = "Example 2" THEN "Name 2"
     WHEN Column1 = "Example 3"
       AND Column2 NOT IN ("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4") THEN "Name 3"
     WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample1", "Sample2") THEN "Name4"
     WHEN Column1 = "Example 3" AND Column2 IN ("Sample3", "Sample4") THEN "Name5"
     ELSE "-" END AS Name,
```

`case when` returns from the first matching condition and then ignores the rest, so you need to make the earlier condition narrower. Alternatively, you could put the Name4/5 conditions before the Name 3 condition.